# Admob Implementation with Unity 5.5, with new api's

Tags: c#, admob, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to figure out how to use admob with a very simple unity created soundboard.  Normally I think I could have figured it out, but it seems google has updated its admob api's that it uses.  Unfortunately I can not find any videos or websites(in English) that show how to implement admob with the new set up.  Any suggestions or explanations would be highly appreciated, looking forward to any replies.  Thanks in advance!  Also worth mentioning, this is for Unity 5.5, in Unity 2d.  We have also already created our admob account.